# 動画をフレームに分けて保存する方法について

Tags: c#

動画をフレームに分けて保存するソフトをつくりたく、この[ウェブサイト](http://elicon.blog57.fc2.com/blog-entry-186.html)からコードを引用し、編集した結果、以下のようになりました。

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;


            FilgraphManager filgraphManager = new FilgraphManager();
            filgraphManager.RenderFile(fileName);
            IBasicVideo bv = (IBasicVideo)filgraphManager;
            int vx, vy;
            bv.GetVideoSize(out vx, out vy);
            var scale = 100F / (float)vx; //100Fのところに出力画像の長辺の長さを入れる
            var w = (int)(scale * vx);
            var h = (int)(scale * vy);

            var md = (IMediaDet)new MediaDet();
            md.Filename = fileName;
            md.CurrentStream = 0;
            string name = @"hoge.bmp";
            md.WriteBitmapBits(5.0d, w, h, name);
        }
    }
}
```

}

エラーないのですが、ボタンを押すとオープンダイアログだけ開き、動画を選択してもなにも起こりません。保存について指定してないからからなのでしょうが、そのやりかたが分かりません。
何方か、動画から得たフレームをDocument\Pictureに新しいフォルダーをつくって保存する方法・コードを教えてくれませんか？

編集１＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿

```
MessageBox.Show(
            strvx + strvy,
            Application.ProductName,
            MessageBoxButtons.OK
            );
```

をif分の一番最後に挿入した結果次のような、メッセージボックスが開きました。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: どこまでは動作しているのでしょうか？ 例えばvx、vyは取得できているのでしょうか？

Comment: 編集結果を見てください、取得できているようです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

上記コードを試してみましたが、画像ファイルの保存名でファイル名しか指定していませんので、プロジェクトのbin\Debugフォルダー（ReleaseビルドならReleaseフォルダー）に画像が保存されました。

Document\Pictureフォルダーに保存したいとのことですので、保存名を下記にすることでPictureフォルダーに画像が保存されます。

```
string name = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures) + @"\hoge.bmp";
```

ご参考として、特殊フォルダー（MyDocumentなど）の取得方法は下記に詳しく記述あります。
http://dobon.net/vb/dotnet/file/getfolderpath.html